# Tomcat pool property QuerytimeoutInterceptor set is overridden by querytimeout set in jdbctemplate

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, jdbctemplate

Tomcat pool property QuerytimeoutInterceptor set is overridden by querytimeout set in jdbctemplate. Is it normal behaviour ?